# Displaying list of random links using wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, links

Is it possible to modify wp_nav_menu to display a list of random links? I tried adding `'orderby' => 'rand'`, but that didn't do anything. I'm afraid my PHP skills are rudimentary, at best.

The rest of the code I'm using to display:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
'menu' => 'Personal',
'orderby' => 'rand', /* not working */
```

Thank you for any guidance. Or, if you know of a different way to accomplish this, besides just throwing all my links in a PHP file and going about it via a random call, please let me know. Thank you so very much! I did this before, years ago, but I can't remember how, and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a way to do this, though not by using wp_nav_menu. Instead, I re-invoked wp_list_bookmarks; and used this code:

```
wp_list_bookmarks('orderby=rand');
```